# Border per column header

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, wpf-style

I want to create a table on wpf that each column header has a round corner this is what i got so far:

[image]

as you can see, i have the desired outcome with a little un desired outcome.
the undesired out come is that the all data grid header itself (not the columns) is getting the same border, i need to make it transparent, how can i do that?

this is the part of the style:

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush"  Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>                                        
                        <Grid>
                            <Border CornerRadius="5 5 0 0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>                                        
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reasons, DataGrid has a blank DataGridColumnHeader in its template. that blank columns doesn't have DataContext value (`null`). So change border brush to transparent in a DataTrigger:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Border CornerRadius="5 5 0 0" BorderThickness="1" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

---

improved version, which uses ContentPresenter in header template and test Content in a trigger

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Grid>
        <Border CornerRadius="5 5 0 0" BorderThickness="1" >
            <ContentPresenter/>                                        
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

header is not necessary a text, e.g.:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <Border Background="Cyan">
                <TextBlock Text="NAME" Margin="5"/>
            </Border>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i needed, thank you so much

Comment: Hi, when i use <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/> and add datacontext it shows me the class of the object inside the datagrid how can i remove it? e.g if my class is ViewModel than in the data grid it shows me all column's headers and another column with the name ViewModel and this column is over other columns

Comment: @Joe, indeed, i didn't use DataContext for my test, only set ItemsSource; with dataContext it doesn't work as expected. see improved version

Comment: thank you i'll try to understand what RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}} means