# Why does my DataGrid add a strange HeaderColumn?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So I'm trying to customize a `DataGrid` control and for some reason it adds the name of the DataContext as a HeaderColumn, why is that? You can see it at the end of this picture.

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="Watcher.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="450" Width="1200"
        Background="#27292D">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

..

<DataGrid Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.Row="1"
          AutoGenerateColumns = "False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Coins}"
          GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
          HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Gray"
          Background="Transparent"
          HeadersVisibility="Column"
          Margin="10,0,0,0"
          BorderThickness="0"
          CanUserAddRows="False">

    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>

    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" 
               TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Gray">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" FontFamily="Fonts/#Poppins" Width="120" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Symbol">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Symbol}"
                                               Width="50" Height="50"
                                               Foreground="#3C82EA"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                               FontFamily="Fonts/#Poppins"
                                               Padding="0,16,0,0"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Name">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                               Width="50" Height="50"
                                               Foreground="#3C82EA"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                               FontFamily="Fonts/#Poppins"
                                               Padding="0,16,0,0"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Price">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat=${0}}"
                                           Width="50" Height="50"
                                           Foreground="Gray"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                           FontFamily="Fonts/#Poppins"
                                           Padding="0,16,0,0"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header = "% Change (24 hrs)">



            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>

                                <Border Height="25" Background="#3A514D" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        CornerRadius="4">
                                    <TextBlock Text="+58.63%" 
                                       Foreground="#4BE299" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                       Padding="6,6,8,6"
                                       Margin="0,1,0,0"
                                       FontFamily="Fonts/#Poppins"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>




        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924746/problems-with-datagridcolumnheader-style, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014542/border-per-column-header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `TemplateBinding` for the column header style:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" 
           TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Gray">
                        <!-- Make change the line below -->
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" FontFamily="Fonts/#Poppins" Width="120" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I had to change the `TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"` on the `ControlTemplate`, besides that it worked like a charm.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to copy that piece of code. LOL